# How to get Access Token from Keycloak over SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, keycloak, access-token

I'm trying to get an Access Token from Keycloak over SpringBoot and did try the following example. But the `KeycloakAuthenticationToken token` is null.

Does someone know another approach to get an Access Token?

```
@GetMapping("/token")
public String getToken(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

    KeycloakAuthenticationToken token = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) request.getUserPrincipal();
    RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext session = (RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext) token.getAccount().getKeycloakSecurityContext();
    KeycloakSecurityContext context = token.getAccount().getKeycloakSecurityContext();


    String accessTokenPretty = JsonSerialization.writeValueAsPrettyString(session.getToken());
    String idTokenPretty = JsonSerialization.writeValueAsPrettyString(session.getIdToken());

    RefreshToken refreshToken;
    try {
        refreshToken = new JWSInput(session.getRefreshToken()).readJsonContent(RefreshToken.class);
    } catch (JWSInputException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
    String refreshTokenPretty = JsonSerialization.writeValueAsPrettyString(refreshToken);

    return refreshTokenPretty;
}
```

Seems like I can get a token like this with ('org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client'):

```
Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder() //
            .serverUrl(serverUrl) //
            .realm(realm) //
            .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD) //
            .clientId(clientId) //
            .clientSecret(clientSecret) //
            .username(userName) //
            .password(password) //
            .build();
AccessTokenResponse tok = keycloak.tokenManager().getAccessToken();
```

If someone knows a more elegant way, I would appreciate if you let me know :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request =
        new TokenRequest.Builder(clientID, OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
                .add("username", userName)
                .add("password", password)
                .build();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity( postUrl, request , String.class );
return response.getBody();
```

and the helper class:

```
public class TokenRequest {
    public static class Builder{
        MultiValueMap<String, String> data;
        public Builder(String clientID, String grant_type){
            data = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            data.put("client_id", Collections.singletonList(clientID));
            data.put("grant_type", Collections.singletonList(grant_type));
        }
        public Builder add(String key, String value){
            data.put(key, Collections.singletonList(value));
            return this;
        }
        public HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>  build(){
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
            return new HttpEntity<>(data, headers);
        }
    }
    private TokenRequest(){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    KeycloakAuthenticationToken keycloakAuthenticationToken = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) request.getUserPrincipal();
    KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext> principal = (KeycloakPrincipal) keycloakAuthenticationToken.getPrincipal();
    String token = principal.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getIdTokenString();
```